# Spring programmatic bean autowired as proxy instead of target

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, proxy, threadpoolexecutor

I created an annotation for creating ThreadPoolTaskExecutors populated with values from the environment. However, when I autowire the bean it gives me a proxy and calling the methods on the proxy gives the wrong values.

If I manually access the target class, then I get the correct values.

```
Executor exec = (Executor) ((Advised) executor).getTargetSource().getTarget();
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExec = (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) exec;
```

I have been scratching my head for a while now as to why I'm getting a proxy bean, but can't seem to figure it out.

I am using an annotation to import my registrar class that implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar to register the bean. The registrar code is below:

```
public class ExecutorEnumerationRegistrar implements ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar, EnvironmentAware {

    public static final String CORE_POOL_SIZE = "corePoolSize";
    public static final String MAX_POOL_SIZE = "maxPoolSize";
    public static final String QUEUE_CAPACITY = "queueCapacity";
    public static final String THREAD_NAME_PREFIX = "threadNamePrefix";
    private static final String REJECTED_EXECUTION_HANDLER = "rejectedExecutionHandler";
    private static final String NAMES = "names";
    private static final String REJECTED_HANDLER = "rejectedHandler";
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void registerBeanDefinitions(AnnotationMetadata importingClassMetadata, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        Map<String, Object> attrs = importingClassMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(ThreadPoolTaskExecutorCreator.class.getName(), true);
        final String[] beanNames = (String[]) attrs.get(NAMES);
        final String[] policyClass = (String[]) attrs.get(REJECTED_HANDLER);
        for (int x = 0; x < beanNames.length; x++) {
            createAndRegisterBean(beanNames[x], policyClass[x], registry);
        }
    }

    private void createAndRegisterBean(String name, String policyClass, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        GenericBeanDefinition bd = new GenericBeanDefinition();
        bd.setBeanClass(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.class);
        bd.setAutowireCandidate(true);
        bd.setRole(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE);
        MutablePropertyValues mpv = bd.getPropertyValues();
        populateProperties(mpv, name, policyClass);
        registry.registerBeanDefinition(name, bd);
    }

    private void populateProperties(MutablePropertyValues mpv, String name, String policyClass) {
        mpv.add(CORE_POOL_SIZE, Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty(name + "." + CORE_POOL_SIZE)));
        mpv.add(MAX_POOL_SIZE, Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty(name + "." + MAX_POOL_SIZE)));
        mpv.add(QUEUE_CAPACITY, Integer.valueOf(env.getProperty(name + "." + QUEUE_CAPACITY)));
        try {
            mpv.add(REJECTED_EXECUTION_HANDLER, Class.forName(policyClass).newInstance());
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mpv.add(THREAD_NAME_PREFIX, name + "-");
    }

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
        env = environment;
    }

}
```

Annotation to import the registrar:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)  
@Target(ElementType.TYPE) 
@Documented 
@Import(ExecutorEnumerationRegistrar.class) 
public @interface ThreadPoolTaskExecutorCreator{ 

    String[] names(); 

    String[] rejectedHandler() default ThreadPoolPolicyHandlers.CALLER_RUNS_POLICY; 

}
```

I have tested with the following code:
Spring Boot Class:

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@ComponentScan("my.test.classes")
@ThreadPoolTaskExecutorCreator(names = {"testExecutor"}, rejectedHandler = ThreadPoolPolicyHandlers.DISCARD_POLICY) 
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
    SessionAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, 
    JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,
    JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
    JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class,
    RedisAutoConfiguration.class, RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})
public class TestBoot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestBoot.class, args);
    }   
}
```

All versions from spring-boot-starter-parent 1.4.5.RELEASE

I wrote a JUnit test that checks the values and it passes. **The only time it doesn't work is when I autowire it in a Spring Boot eureka application.** Is there anything I can do so that it doesn't autowire a proxy bean? I have searched through the documentation and looked at all the related classes, but I don't see anything related to why it's a proxy. Also, why does it give incorrect values when accessed through the proxy?

Comment: What do you mean by "it gives incorrect values"? Can you share the code for injection and usage of  `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor ` in your code ...?

Comment: I'm simply autowiring it in another spring bean. I'm printing out the values for the core pool size, max pool size, and queue capacity. It returns the default values instead of the properties sent when created.

Comment: I'm asking, as your code works perfectly well for me :) May be you can share the version of Spring / Spring Boot at least?

Comment: Ah yea I should have put that in the question. Sorry about that. It's Spring Boot 1.4.5 and Spring 4.3.4. I tried testing this in a simple test project by just using SpringBootApplication and a singleton bean I created, but it still gives a proxy.

Comment: Tried your code with 1.4.5 and it works perfectly well. Seems you have some additional configuration which breaks it. So it would be perfect if you share more configuration code (no business logic is needed)

Comment: I updated the question. Yea, sorry I am multi-tasking and noticing I'm forgetting some details that would help

Comment: And where do you do your import? I mean where do you define the `ExecutorEnumerationRegistrar` ?

Comment: I accidentally deleted it, but it's on the spring boot test class.

Comment: No, I mean where is the import of 'ExecutorEnumerationRegistrar'? It will not be automatically discovered by spring, you need to manually tell the Spring about it. Seems that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are missing the code for registering the instance of your `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` ( in your example that is `ExecutorEnumerationRegistrar` )
So there are two ways to register the `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` use the `@Import` annotation directly or implement the `ImportSelector` interface which can give you more generic configuration options.

For your case simply adding the `@Import({ExecutorEnumerationRegistrar.class})` on the `Configuration` class will do the trick.

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@ComponentScan("my.test.classes")
@ThreadPoolTaskExecutorCreator(names = {"testExecutor"}, rejectedHandler = ThreadPoolPolicyHandlers.DISCARD_POLICY)
// THIS IS REQUIRED
@Import({ExecutorEnumerationRegistrar.class})
// See Above
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
SessionAutoConfiguration.class,
DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, 
JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,
JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, 
JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration.class,
RedisAutoConfiguration.class, RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class})
public class TestBoot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestBoot.class, args);
    }   
}
```

and just remember to use the `@Qualifier` when autowiring the instance of `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. See example component

```
@Component
public class Component {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("testExecutor")
    private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor exec;

    // you methods
}
```

Comment: I was already importing the registrar via my ThreadPoolTaskExecutorCreator annotation. I have added the code for that as well. I have debugged and tested this code many times. It goes into the registrar and creates the bean. It also autowires it. The problem is, it's autowiring a proxy.